# HQL - update on @Embeddable object in a map

Tags: hibernate, jpa, hql

I have a JPA Entity, that contains a map of another embedded entity.
It looks like this:
@Entity

```
public class ParentEntity {
    @Id
    @Column(name = "ID", nullable = false)
    private Long id;
    [...columns ...]
    @ElementCollection(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @CollectionTable(name = "EMBEDDED_ENTITY", joinColumns =@JoinColumn(name = "PARENT_ID"))
    @MapKeyColumn(name = "MAP_KEY")
    private Map<Long, EmbeddedEntity> embeddedEntities;
    @Column(name = "STATUS", nullable = false)
    private int status;
}

@Embeddable
public class EmbeddedEntity{
    @Column(name = "SOME_VALUE", nullable = false)   
    private String someValue;
}
```

This works perfactly fine, and when I select ParentEntity, I get EmbeddedEntities in a map as expected.
Now I am trying to write an HQL update that would actually update "someValue" columns for the embedded entity with specific key. I tried:

```
update ParentEntity set embeddedEntities[?1].someValue= ?2 where status = ?3
```

But this raises exception, that "[" character is unexpected. So I changed it to:

```
update ParentEntity set embeddedEntities.someValue= ?2 where status= ?3 and index(embeddedEntities) = ?1
```

Which looks legit ;) but I get an exception

```
Caused by: org.hibernate.QueryException: could not resolve property: someValue of: ParentEntity
```

Which simple tells me that hibernate did not understand the idea, since I said that it needs to update "someValue" field of embeddedEntities property (map) and not "someValue" field of the ParentEntity itself.

Is what I am doing achievable via HQL? It is not Idea to do the select and change the values in the code, since there can be thousands of EmbeddedEntity rows in the DB.

Comment: looks legit ? embeddedEntities is a MAP. You cannot do embeddedEntities.someValue in Java can you?! BULK UPDATE does NOT cater for such things

Comment: @NeilStockton so You say that is impossible to do via HQL?
*Nevertheless embeddedEntities is a property in ParentEntity